# sceptics.stackexchange.com should redirect

Tags: feature-request

Sceptics is a common spelling in the UK.

It should redirect to the US spelling with a 'k'.

I am asking this question from a phone at a Skeptics event after a newbie tripped over it. I only mention this because if the minimum length.

Comment: Agreed. It's been requested once before: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/sceptics-se-should-redirect-to-skeptics-se but nobody did anything about it. math/maths point to the same place, so it can be done.